# Can I add multiple entries to one column attribute in my rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design, sqlite

I'm building a job board in the rails framework. I'm setting up my job scaffold and running into an issue.

The employer will be able to set the `job_title`, `job_location`, `salary`, `description`, `required_education`, `required_major` `required_experience`, and so forth. In some job postings, you'll see employers put in their description, "Minimum Education Requirement is a BS in Computer Science or related field." I'm trying to add numerous fields in my db under the `required_major` column so the employer can add the related degrees. For example, if the employer will accept a Bachelors degree in Computer Science, Software Engineering, Computer Engineering, or Information Technology; I want to be able to add multiple majors for the `required_major` field. Would I be able to create a subfield of this column so it would have all the degrees listed or should I have numerous columns (ex. `required_major1` `required_major2`, etc.).

Here is my current schema for the jobs table:

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160103030240) do

create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|

```
t.integer  "company_id"
t.string   "job_title"
t.string   "job_location"
t.decimal  "salary",              precision: 8, scale: 2
t.text     "description"
t.string   "required_education"
t.string   "required_major"
t.string   "required_experience"
t.datetime "created_at",                                  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                                  null: false
```

end

Right now, I'm just going to start with a single degree field and expand on it as I build. Any input on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, your title is somewhat vague and you don't really get specific in your post. Can you show some of what you have, and give a specific example of what you want to have?

Comment: Is `related field` just a system of tags? Would the 'related field` correspond to some other part of the DB?

Comment: I will edit my post so there is no more confusion. I will explain what I mean then post my code.

Comment: This seems like required education is a mapping table (HABTM in the parlance of ActiveRecord).  It would connect each posting to a table of university majors.  You can also abstract out the level (associates, bachelors, masters, doctorate) and join to that table.

Comment: Harper, could you point me in a direction where I can learn more about this and mapping in general? That should solve my problem and also others that are very similar to this exact question.